How to fix my routing problem using NordVpn?
I setup RaspAP (the easiest, full-featured wireless router setup for Debian-based devices) using a Raspberry Pi4.
I'm able to connect to Wi-Fi provided by the built-in adapter wlan0 and navigate internet using the connection on eth0.
The problem is when I fire up NordVPN connection, routing it's not working anymore and I'm not able to navigate.
Is it possible to do with the above configuration, does RaspAP support what I would like to do without using or add external adapter ?
My configuration (which works):
Modem_ISP<----->(eth0)-Raspberry-(wlan0)<----->Client
public IP<--------->192.168.x.x <---->10.3.141.1<----->10.3.141.x.

My configuration (which does not work):
-------------------> NordVPN_IP_ADDR<---->10.3.141.1<----->10.3.141.x

There is a guide/howto ?
